# table tr is not replaced properly as expected

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have to one public_page.php page and one action.php page. If a user press submit button in public_page.php it sends information to action.php page by jquery post method. After successful processing the action.php page sends one tr data which should be replaced in table of public_page.php.

```
page: public_page.php
<div id="result"></div>
<table>
 <thead><tr><th>S/N</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr id="1"><td>1</td><td>Mr.X</td><td>Japan</td><td>95684256</td><td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a></td></tr>
    <tr id="5"><td>1</td><td>Mr.Y</td><td>USA</td><td>123856641</td><td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a></td></tr>
    <tr id="8"><td>1</td><td>Mr.Z</td><td>UK</td><td>456862043</td><td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a></td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

jquery code (without $(document).ready line here):

```
$("body").on("click",".edit",function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = 'action.php';
  var trid = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    $.post(url,
    {
      trid: trid,
    },function(data){
        $("#result").html(data).show();
    });
});
```

after that the data of table row is come in '#result' div for editing. Let. tr id=5 (Mr.Y) is now for editing. So here it is comes in #result div as follows:

```
<div id="result">
<form id="5000">
Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="Mr.Y" /><br />
Address:<input type="text" name="adrs" value="USA" /><br />
Mobile:<input type="text" name="mobile" value="123856641" /><br />
Age:<input type="text" name="age" value="30" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</div>
```

Now when user edit the information and press Submit, it sends the form information to action.php page by jquery. what is doing action.php page, after getting trid (which is actually id of database row that is to be edited) it process the data and produce callback data for public_page.php like this:

```
page: action.php
echo '<div class="success_msg">Data Updated Successfully!</div>';
echo '<div class="trid">5</div>';
echo '<div class="trcontent"><tr id="5"><td>1</td><td>Mr.Y</td><td>Tokeyo</td><td>123856641</td><td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a></td></tr></div>';
```

and jquery code of public_page.php process the data like this:

```
   var url = 'action.php';
    var id = $(this).closest('form').attr('id');
    var form_id = "#"+id ;
    var data = $(form_id).serializeArray();
    $.post(url,
      data,function(callbackdata){
        var msg = $(callbackdata).filter(".success_msg").html();
        var trid = $(callbackdata).filter(".trid").html();
        var trdata = $(callbackdata).filter(".trcontent").html();
        $("#result").html(msg).show();
        $('#'+trid).replaceWith(trdata);
    });
```

as per query code, it should replace the tr which id is 5. But although it is replacing the tr but not in tabular format, it is replacing as text format like this:

```
page: public_page.php
<div id="result"></div>
<table>
 <thead><tr><th>S/N</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Mobile</th><th>Action</th></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr id="1"><td>1</td><td>Mr.X</td><td>Japan</td><td>95684256</td><td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a></td></tr>
    1Mr.YTokeyo123856641<a class="edit" href="">Edit</a>
    <tr id="8"><td>1</td><td>Mr.Z</td><td>UK</td><td>456862043</td><td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a></td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I think ...... is not inserting with replaced data.

How to resolve this issue, so that after replacing tr id="5" looks like a table row, not a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest making an edit that will deal with this in a simpler way.

In your php code, instead of returning a div, what you should return is data.

```
<?php
$data = new stdClass();
$data->successMsg = 'Data Updated Successfully!';
$data->trid = 5;
$data->trContent = '<tr id="5"><td>1</td><td>Mr.Y</td><td>Tokeyo</td><td>123856641</td><td><a class="edit" href="">Edit</a></td></tr>';

echo json_encode($data);
```

Then in your JS code, you can go directly at the data instead of filtering it out of your HTML.

```
$.post(url,
      data,
      function(callbackdata){
        var msg = callbackdata.successMsg;
        var trid = callbackdata.trid;
        var trdata = callbackdata.trContent;
        $("#result").html(msg).show();
        $('#'+trid).replaceWith(trdata);
      }, 
      'json');
```

The reason you're having problems is because of the way jQuery handles invalid HTML. `<div><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></div>` is not valid.

```
$('<div><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></div>').html() // outputs `12`
```

Comment: Don't know why, it is not showing any change from public_page.php after getting the callbackdata. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Your code was not working as you forget to give "json" after closing curly braces of funcion(callbackdata). Anyway thanks for your help. If you will correct your code, then I will accept your answer.

Comment: @AbdullahMamun-Ur-Rashid you're correct, I updated answer to include the 'json' data type.